# change the listing type of categories block?

Tags: categories, css

How ist it possible to display the categories in the sidebar ( cat. block )
like this:

cat1, cat2, cat3
cat4, cat5, cat6

and NOT

cat1
cat2
cat3
cat4
cat5
cat6

Can you help ?

THANKS in adv.

best wishes

Comment: Can we see your code that generates the output you don't want?

Answer (score 0):

In WordPress, you can achieve the desired format of displaying categories in the sidebar as "cat1, cat2, cat3 cat4, cat5, cat6" by creating a custom widget or by modifying the default Category widget with a little bit of CSS.

Here's how you can do it:

Custom Widget

Create a Custom HTML Widget:
In your WordPress dashboard, go to Appearance > Widgets.
Add a "Custom HTML" widget to your sidebar.
In the widget content, use HTML to format your categories as needed.

For example:

html

```
<span class="category">cat1,</span>

<span class="category">cat2,</span>

<span class="category">cat3</span>

<span class="category">cat4,</span>

<span class="category">cat5,</span>

<span class="category">cat6</span>
```

Add CSS for Styling:
To style your custom category list, you can add CSS to your theme. You can do this in the theme's customizer or by adding CSS to your theme's style.css file.
For example:

css

.category-list {

```
display: flex;

flex-wrap: wrap;
```

}

.category {

```
margin-right: 5px; /* Adjust the margin as needed to control the spacing between categories */
```

}

If you want to get more inspiration and ideas you can visit [Apkozone](https://apkozone.com/) to look for something interesting.